# How to use Ctrl+Z to stop asking for input?

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

I am writing a program that takes integers from the user and stores them in an array, then calculates the arrays average.

The array can hold at maximum 100 integers. If the user wants to do less than 100, they hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> (or <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>) to stop prompting for numbers.

Here is my main method:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    int [] array = new int[100];
        System.out.printf("Enter a stream of numbers: ");
         readIntoArray(input, array);
        for (int i = 0; i<=array.length;i++) {
            array[i] = input.nextInt();
        }
    }
```

And here is the method that reads into the array.

```
public static int readIntoArray(Scanner input, int[] nums) {
    int count = 0; //number of elements entered into the array
    while (count <= nums.length && input.hasNextInt()) {
        nums[count]=input.nextInt();
        count++;        
    } 
    return count;
}
```

And here is the average method.

```
public static void printAboveAverage(int[] nums, int size) {
    double average;
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        sum =+ nums[i];
    }

    average = sum/size;     
    System.out.print(average);
```

What am I doing wrong?

I keep getting a `NoSuchElementException` immediately after hitting <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled because I don't see any code that handles key presses. Did you omit that? Or is there some default, standardized behavior for CTRL+Z in a Java program?

Comment: @domsson No, obviously not. CTRL+Z closes the input stream and that is handled by the OS, not Java.

Comment: Nice question for a newbie! But for the record: ideally, you give us [mcve] ... code that can be compiled / ran by us without additional effort. In that sense, your input could be improved - to contain the complete class, without explanations inbetween. So I just go copy/paste/run.

Comment: @Tom that wasn't obvious to me; I didn't know that CTRL+Z closes the input stream. Thanks for telling me. Still wondering if this is true for every OS though.

Comment: @Tom Well, its handled by Java in a roundabout way. `Scanner.hasNext` will return false after the stream's been closed.

Comment: @Michael This is correct, but not what domsson asked. He asked where OP handles the keystroke ctrl+z, but it is not OP who has to handled that. He just needs to handle results of closing the stream, or prevent an issue when the stream is closed, like using a hasXYZ method (like you also suggested).

Comment: @Tom Gimme a break. Reading is hard :(

Comment: @Tom Nice editing. I have to remember that CTRL button thingy ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
while (count <= nums.length && input.hasNextInt()) {
```

This loop will probably stop when you hit ctrl-z and *there is no more int*. But next statement is:

```
array[i] = input.nextInt();
```

In other words: your read method *seems* to correctly check if enough numbers are in, **or** if the scanner stopped having input.

But your main method ignores that, and just asks for **another** number from the scanner.

So it could be as simple as: just drop that for loop within your main method that wants more numbers.

Comment: Thank you both for your help! Yes, I understand fully. Thanks so much!

Comment: I am glad to hear that ... and let me think about the other answer I put up to your older question.

Answer (score -2):

I suggest you have a try and catch if it gives you an Exception, maybe use it to get unlimited numbers (dont use the max 100 numbers) and when he finds the exception he counts the average?

Not the best solution, excpetion are not meant to always be used, Thanks to  domsson for the reminder

something like:

```
try{
    //Get the numbers
}
catch(Exception e){
    //Calculate the average
}
```

Just thinking out loud, it may help you.

Comment: Exceptions are for exceptional circumstances; they should not be used for regular program flow.

Comment: you are correct, as I said, It is not the best solution, but it may work

Comment: It is not only "not the best" solution. It is just a poor attempt to get around missing problem understanding. But you dont work around problems, you dig until you understand them, and then you fix  them.